# Why corflags.exe can't change PE32+ to PE32?

Tags: .net, x86, 64-bit, corflags

I always build my assemblies to x64 platform, but now my client asked me to provide assemblies of the two platforms (x86 & x64).

So, I think I can use corflags.exe to change PE32+ to PE32 after building my project for x64 platform only.

But corflags didn't support this operation. Why not?

My perception is that MSIL should be same between x86, x64 and AnyCPU except for some tags and headers. Am I wrong?

Comment: The "PE32+" executable file format is fundamentally different.  Its internal data structures uses 64-bit values in many places.  Turning a 64-bit executable file into a 32-bit file is very untrivial and not a feature of CorFlags.  Targeting x64 for a library is always a mistake, use AnyCPU to take advantage of .NET code being able to run on any architecture.  Unless you know for a fact that it can never run in 32-bit mode.  In which case you of course have to say "no".

Comment: Thank your reply, Hans Passant. Please let me clarify again. MSIL kept  inside the PE file, and it will be compiled to 32bit or 64bit  machine code by flag at runtime. However some data structures in the PE file already used 64bit values when chose the x64 target platform, and can't convert to the 32bit. This is a main reason for Corflags can not have this feature, right ?

Comment: By the way, the internal data structures is uses 32bit or 64bit when chose AnyCPU ?